# Inserir link streaming em pagina - HTML

Tags: html, html5, streaming

Então, estou tentando implementar um link streaming "rtmp" a uma pagina html, mas sem sucesso, já tentei diversos modo mas nenhum que surtisse efeito, o link abaixo e o que eu quero que seja exibido na pagina html.

```
 rtmp://192.168.1.168:1935/hls/hd-live
```

tambem ja tentei algo do tipo

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
 <source src="rtmp://192.168.1.168:1935/hls/hd-live" type="rtmp/mp4">
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O navegador sempre retorna que não nenhum vídeo com formato ou tipo MIME suportados, se alguém puder ajudar, por favor, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Eu nunca usei RTMP más, considere se seu servidor esta devolvendo o `MIME` correto ao recurso solicitado? Niginx possui o arquivo `mime.types` outras soluções cono Node podem estar sujeitas a pacotes definirem o mime type. Considere investigar por ai, adicionar mais informações relevantes de seu servidor na pergunta. Boa sorte

Comment: O `rtmp` é voltado para o *flash*, mas tente com o http://videojs.com/getting-started/